# Permit oauth2 urls in SecurityFilterChain's requestMatchers

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

We have multiple `SecurityFilterChain`s.

Users of our `*.jsp` UI must be authenticated with `oauth2`:

```java
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChainJsps(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers((requestMatchers) -> requestMatchers.antMatchers("/*.jsp", "/oauth2/**", "/login/**"))
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeHttpRequests -> authorizeHttpRequests
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2Login(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
```

For oauth2 to work the oauth2 urls `"/oauth2/**"` and `"/login/**"` must be included in the `requestMatchers.antMatchers` list, otherwise users will get an 404 error.

Adding the oauth2 urls manually is error-prone.  This example is for instance missing the `"/logout"` url.

**Is there an easier way to include all oauth2 urls?

If not, how do I get a list of oauth2 urls which must be matched?**